# Delivering data between two viewControllers via “NSKeyedArchiver ” causes double “import” error?

Tags: ios, delegates, nskeyedarchiver, nsnotification

I am a new iOS developer. These days, I have been stuck in a problem : delivering data between two viewControllers via “NSKeyedArchiver ” causes double “import”, by which I mean both the two viewControllers import each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to share/stored data, if you don't want to use the methods you mentioned above, is to use NSUserDefaults. This is a local store that you can use to save off your data to.  [See docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

Comment: NSUserDefaults is suggested  to record user’s preferences..    But what i need to store is the common  data  like  a customized stuff which consist  of several Object-C objects --

Comment: Then you should look at creating a shared model that your views can read and write to or use one of the other methods you have already mentioned above.